# Using a standard React(with Webpack) boilerplate, with PHP backend

Tags: apache, reactjs, .htaccess, webpack

I'm having serious trouble, integrating one php script into my react project. The React file structure is fairly standard:
[image: Image of my file structure, and .htaccess content]

I'm using xampp as my apache server. I've setup a virtual host, whose root document is the public folder.

The React app it self works fine, but the problem is the AJAX requests to the php script(server/search_db.php). With this .htaccess code present, the result is the entire index.html file content being returned in the ajax response. Without this code, however, the React app it self doesn't work, once i use its routing, being that each request goes to an actual file, that obviously isn't there..

I've tried many things, and just can't get it working.
This is my webpack.config file, if relevant..:
[image: Webpack.config.js]

Edit: here is where the ajax request if fired from:
[image: Ajax is fired from src/actions folder]

Any help setting this up will be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Can you please show the lines where the ajax request is fired? I need some more background to help you. By the way: This is the reason I don't use all of this boilerplate stuff at all. There are some other ways to build your react app so that you won't get into these strange troubles :-D

Comment: I've edited the post and added another image :-)

Comment: Ok this was very helpful :-D (I'm always surprised how much boilerplate stuff can be used just to build a small UI on a REST API, but I understand the reasons to do so). What I now need is the original address where the request is sent to (not any referred one). Can you look it up in your browser dev console and post it, too?

Comment: cms.localhost/server/search_db.php?show_duplicate_titles&page=1 is this what u mean?

Comment: this might help - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-react-app-with-laravel-backend-part-2-react--cms-29443